# Why can't i use AngularJS' ng-view and routing in combination with jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, pug

So i'm currently trying to learn about the MEAN stack. Express uses jade by default and although i know i can just as easily use html i thought i would try it out.
Now, when i try to route with angular like this:

```
...
body
  div(ng-view)

  script.
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/',
          {
            templateUrl: 'partial1.jade'
          })
        .otherwise(
          {
            templateUrl: 'partial1.jade'
          });
    });
```

with partial1.jade simple as:

```
h1 Title
```

The resulting html will be:

```
<span class="ng-scope ng-binding">h1 Title</span>
```

So everything in partial.jade is automatically caught in a span-element. When i use html instead of jade it works perfectly fine, of course.

So i guess angular uses the jade file without it being pre-processed, but if i understand correctly angular is purely client-side and the jade pre-processor sits on the server-side. So how is it possible that angular gets the pure jade file?

And also, is there a way i can still use jade in combination with angular's routing?

Comment: "the jade pre-processor sits on the server-side" You can verify that this works by directly opening 'partial1.jade' in a web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's loading the pure jade file because you're telling it to: `templateUrl: 'partial1.jade'`. Angular doesn't know what Jade is and definitely can't dynamically parse it into HTML. You need to compile the Jade at build time and have Angular load the compiled HTML versions of your partials.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! But at what point are jade files normally compiled then? 'cause when i change a jade file, i don't have to restart the server in order to see the changes..

Comment: Jade files are normally compiled by the server whenever they are requested. You could also make a request to a program on your server that will dynamically compile the Jade files, but seeing as they are static Angular templates that don't need any server-generated content, it makes no sense to do it that way. You should compile them on save or on build, and load the HTML as described above. Look into using `grunt` with `watch` to automatically compile your Jade to HTML on save.